# Join two rows into one in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, rows

Hello i´m apologize but i cant resolve this issue... im beginner and dont know how to do... i have code

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.surname, b.contact
FROM crm_client a
JOIN crm_client_contact b ON ( a.id = b.id_client ) 
WHERE id_iz =  '98'
```

which results me

```
name1 surname1 email1
name1 surname1 phonenumber1
name2 surname2 email2
name2 surname2 phonenumber2
```

i would like have phonenumber in next column
email and phonenumber has id_contact column... where 1 is for phone and 2 for email...
Cany somebody help me?

Comment: Provide sample data and your table definition

Comment: yes id_contact has only this two values...  email and phone...

Answer (score 0):

If this is always the format -> only phone number + email per name , then you can simply do this:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.surname, MAX(b.contact) as email, MIN(b.contact) as phone_number
FROM crm_client a
JOIN crm_client_contact b ON ( a.id = b.id_client ) 
WHERE id_iz =  '98'
GROUP BY a.firstname,a.surname
```

This should work because numbers are located lower on the ASCI table then letters, therefore - `MIN` will select the phone number, and `MAX` will select the email address.

Note that if it's possible for only 1 value to exists, both column will contain it.

Comment: This is working, thank you... but it will take too much time... there is about 300 000 rows... and i havent got access to the console. Btw i add ORDER BY id_client; and this is not working whith it...

Comment: Is it possible to implement option  check and move if in the phone number is in the email to the correct column?

Comment: and new problem was found...  Duplicate entry 'Stanislava-HencovÃ¡ *' for key 'group_key'

Comment: This make error:  Error writing file '/tmp/MYx5bZQc' (Errcode: 28)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with group_concat & string function

```
select a.`firstname`, a.`surname`,
substring_index(group_concat(b.`contact`),',',1) as email,
substring_index(group_concat(b.`contact`),',',-1) as phone
from crm_client a
join crm_client_contact b ON ( a.id = b.id_client ) 
where id_iz =  '98'
group by a.`firstname`, a.`surname`
```

Comment: To: M Khalid Junaid  #1054 - Unknown column 'a.contact' in 'field list'